# In Debezium is there a way to route tables to different topics?

Tags: regex, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

My tables:

1. users
2. clients
3. notifications
4. alerts

By default I want information to go to topic `user_service.$tableName` but for specific tables, I want the information in different tables.

Expected Output

1. users => user_service.users
2. clients => user_service.clients
3. notifications => notification_service.notifications
4. alerts => alert_service.alerts

I have the configuration that is working for one table like notifications but not sure how I can adjust if for multiple tables

Existing Config:

```
"transforms": "unwrap,Reroute",
"transforms.Reroute.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ByLogicalTableRouter",
"transforms.Reroute.topic.regex": "(.*)notifications",
"transforms.Reroute.topic.replacement": "notificaton_service.notifications",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working with

```
"transforms": "unwrap,Reroute",
"transforms.Reroute.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ByLogicalTableRouter",
"transforms.Reroute.topic.regex": "(.*)(notifications|alerts)",
"transforms.Reroute.topic.replacement": "$2_service.$2",
```